# c code for logf function

Tags: c, math

I am working on a platform, which doesn't have the math library, but I need to use the **logf** function (natural log with floating point input). I tried to search the code for **logf** but in vain. Can somebody provide or give a link for **logf** function code.

Comment: Any platform which supports floating points.

Comment: You're working on 'any platform' ?

Comment: What does log function have to do with a platform?

Comment: Because the best thing to do might vary depending on which platform you are actually on? Or was your question actually "How can I implement `logf` without using the standard math library"?

Comment: Akash, I didn't want an optimized solution, just needed something that works :)!

Comment: Well I guess that's fair enough... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have math library, you can go to libc to look for the code ->

http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=math/w_logf.c

And see how logf calls __ieee754_logf ->

http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/e_logf.c

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a few references to logf() functions which just use casting around log(), such as:

```
float logf(float _X)
{
  return ((float)log((double)_X));
}
```

http://www.raspberryginger.com/jbailey/minix/html/lib_2math_2log_8c-source.html is an implementation of log() (though I have no personal experience with the function there, I merely found it while googling).

Comment: Don't use `_X` as an identifier; `_[A-Z]` is reserved for the implementation and (IIRC) causes undefined behavior. Also, the explicit casts aren't necessary and may actually hide bugs.

Comment: If `logf()` is missing due to non-present math library, how likely is it that `log()` is present?

Comment: @glglgl: Quite likely, since log() is C89 (ANSI C), whereas logf() was added only in C99, and many vendors still don't support it.

Comment: @janneb Ouch, wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @glglgl -- this would be why I provided a link to a log() implementation ;)